# What is the Morse index of the Scherk surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

The Scherk surfaces are properly embedded, complete minimal surfaces
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha \subset \mathbf{R}^3
\end{equation}
that are asymptotic at infinity to the union of two planes $\Pi_1, \Pi_2 \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ which form the angle $\alpha$ along their intersection.

It is relatively obvious that they have infinite Morse index. However, one can quotient $S_\alpha$ by the discrete group $\mathbf{Z}$ corresponding to its periodicity along the axis $\Pi_1 \cap \Pi_2$, yielding a minimal surface
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_\alpha := S_\alpha / \mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{R}^2 \times \mathbf{R} / \mathbf{Z}.
\end{equation}

> What is the Morse index of $\Sigma_\alpha$? Does it have Jacobi fields in addition to those generated by isometries of $\mathbf{R}^3$ fixing $\Pi_1 \cap \Pi_2$?

Comment: This is a nice question, I suspect it's not known in the literature but possibly computable. I would suspect that something in the paper by Montiel-Ros is relevant. Note that there are Jacobi fields on Scherk coming from "varying $\alpha$" but these won't be $L^\infty$ as you can see geometrically.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thanks Otis, I'll be sure to take a look!

Answer (score 1):

These questions are indeed answered by the [paper of Montiel and Ros](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0083639) that Otis suggested in his comment. In fact you can ask more generally for the index and $L^\infty$ nullity of $S_\alpha / m\mathbf{Z}$ for any integer (number of fundamental periods) $m \geq 1$. Corollary 15 of the Montiel-Ros paper (which does not mention the Scherk surfaces specifically) implies that the index is is $2m-1$ and the nullity $3$, independently of the value of $\alpha$.